# How to add Gradle plugins dynamically based on Android build variant/flavor

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In an Android project it has a few build variants (and flavors).
There is one variant it does not want to apply plugin `com.google.gms.google-services`.

tried this in app's build.gradle.kts

```
if (!getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests()
        .toString().contains("nogms")) {
    apply(plugin = "com.google.gms.google-services")
}
```

when do sync the `getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests()` always returns empty

```
[DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[],projectPath='null',rootDir='null'}]
```

**What is the suggested way to dynamically apply plugin based on the chosen build variant?**